# Official Elasticsearch PHP Module enable TTL

Tags: php, elasticsearch, ttl

I know how i could activate the ttl feature with curl in php, but i wonder if the offical Elasticsearch PHP Library (https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php) does this feature support as well. I've already dig trough the code of the Lib but was not able to figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried submitting the TTL in the `$params` array? Look at the [Clients code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php/blob/2c06a6284e4c3ec0ad63a304b16f3698abc11094/src/Elasticsearch/Client.php#L732)

Comment: Yes, i did... But i need to activate the ttl feature in the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created my own method to enable ttl feature on a index type. I've also filed an issue on the official Github Repo: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php/issues/62

```
class ElasticSearchClient extends \Elasticsearch\Client {
  public function enableTtl($params) {
    $index = $this->extractArgument($params, 'index');
    $type = $this->extractArgument($params, 'type');
    $body = json_encode(array($type => array('_ttl' => array('enabled' => true))));
    /** @var callback $endpointBuilder */
    $endpointBuilder = $this->dicEndpoints;

    /** @var \Elasticsearch\Endpoints\Update $endpoint */
    $endpoint = $endpointBuilder('Indices\Mapping\Put');
    $endpoint->setIndex($index)
        ->setType($type)
        ->setBody($body);
    $endpoint->setParams($params);
    $response = $endpoint->performRequest();
    return $response['data'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO you need to update the elasticsearch mapping using the putMapping() method. No need for a special method call.

Here is an example that worked in our system.

```
    $params['index'] = 'yourindexname';
    $params['type'] = 'yourtypename';

    $mapping = [
        '_ttl' => [
            'enabled' => 'true',
            'default' => '14d',
        ],
        'properties' => [
            [... add your properties here ...]
        ]
    ];

    $params['body']['yourtypename'] = $mapping;
    $this->getClient()->indices()->putMapping($params);
```